# Reputation limit for user name change?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names, help

Do you have to have a certain amount of reputation points to change your user name? I have checked all of the questions on changing my user name and the answers that are given say to click the edit button on my profile, they even have pictures demonstrating where it is, but I don't see it on my profile. Any help?

Edit: Never mind. I found the edit tab on Meta Stackoverflow. I was trying to find it on stackexchange.com, but I think what I have to do is change it for each site. Is this correct? I also think that it wasn't appearing on my phone's browser, because I did check meta before on my android.

Comment: Under all the boxes where you can put data you'll see a couple of options, one for just the site you are on and one for all sites.

Comment: It is. How do I delete it?

Comment: To update your profile on your all accounts click `Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts` instead of `Save Profile`.